# How to Clamp rotation of a turret

Tags: unity, rotation

I'm going mad to clamp rotation of an object.

I've tested using Inspector that correctly rotation range is Z>-15 and Z<30.

I've written this code but it isn't working properly !

```
if (rb.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z > 30)
    rb.transform.Rotate (-Vector3.forward * speedTurretMovement  , Space.Self);
if (rb.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z < -15 )
    rb.transform.Rotate (Vector3.forward * speedTurretMovement , Space.Self);
```

Thanks

Comment: 2 things : 1) You are not really clamping the values between -15 and 30, rather you are trying to apply a reverse rotation and do not control what the new angle will be. 2) `it isn't working properly` is a very poor bug description. What is it supposed to mean exactly?

Comment: Yes I know, you're right. What I mean is "how to limit via code the rotation of an object ... how to say Unity : "despite the user input, DON'T rotate that object over this value"

Comment: You need to use [Mathf.Clamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) function for this.

Comment: Usually these required some exra logic because -15 degrees may well get represented as 345 degrees, in which your clamping &c won't work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Body : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject head; //ref the head / turret via inspector
    public int angle = 0;
    public int min = -15;
    public int max =  30;

    void Update ()
    {
        angle += Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) ? 1 : 0;
        angle += Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) ? -1 : 0;
        angle = Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
        head.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, angle, 0);
    }
}
```

Create a **new**, clean scene. Create a cube `GameObject` called `Body` and drop this script on it. Create another cube called `Head` and drop it inside the `Body`. Drag inspector connection for `Head` onto the `Body` script. Make sure they are both at world origin. Use arrow keys to control. Have fun.

P.S. Nothing stops you from calling this script `Head` and dropping it on `Head` instead. I just like the idea of the `Head` controlling the `Body`, and providing angular constraints.

Comment: Pefect! Thank you. I've just changed eulerAngles with localEulerAngles because my turret is "child" of another object already rotated!!! Thanks

Comment: @stighy You're welcome. Would you assign the bounty / checkmark if this solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

just use `Mathf.Clamp(value,min,max);`

Comment: why has this got down votes when it works? there really isn't much to explain here.

Comment: Probably because this is not a detailed answer as was explicitly requested below the question.

Comment: @JustinWilliamStanleyBryant Sorry I am late for answering. I did downvote as this is a very lazy answer imho. Tbh it feels like you just read the title, saw `clamp`, and answered without trying to understand OP's problem. For example OP was doing a 1st rotation going too far, then 2nd rotation to go back to normal. Where do you include your clamp? Before doing the 1st rotation? After it? Many things you could have added to get an upvote instead of downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
rb.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, Mathf.Clamp(transform.eulerAngles.z + rotationAmount * Time.deltaTime, -15, 30)));
```

If you don't want to use `Quaternion`.

```
direction = -1 or 1
rb.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, Mathf.Clamp(speedTurretMovement * direction, -15 - rb.transform.eulerAngles.z, 30 - rb.transform.eulerAngles.z)), Space.Self);
```

Comment: Code like that is difficult to debug, because when the compiler tells you "Error on line X" you're left wondering "where, exactly, on line X?". Break it down into individual statements instead of thinking that a massive one-liner is useful. It's better for you and better for the person you're trying to help.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer I don't think that it is so complicated that it will be hard to debug.... Is it better to create a variable inside update loop to allocate memory every frame? But ofc it will be easier to debug. I post only solutions and best performance practices. If you are concerned about readability it's your responsibility to make it "easier to debug". It doesn't change answer and code correctness, code does what it is supposed to do. Thanks.